# VBA - Cannot create dropdown list for UserForm9.ListBox1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Need help to create dropdown list in UserForm9.ListBox1.  My code below... The error I get is "Run Time Error 380 - Object doesn't support his property or method."  -- which doesn't make sense to me because my object is a ListBox and you can create a dropdown list in a listbox, right???  Btw, why is the word "offset" lower-case??? How to reset???

```
'''''--------------------------

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

     For Each EmployeeID In Sheets("MasterID").Range("A10:A700")     '<<<< Raw data 690 employee id's
        With UserForm9.ListBox1
        .AddItem EmployeeID.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = EmployeeID.offsset(0, 1).Value
        End With
     Next EmployeeID

'''''--------------------------

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

     With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then
            EmployeeID.Text = ""
        Else
            EmployeeID.Text = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys... I got the answer -- I misspelled offsset!!  omg... sorry